# how to send an List<Integer> to a HTTP Get web service in android

Tags: android, web-services

I need to send an `List<Integer>` to a web service

```
public void SendRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> postData,
        String httpMethod, Type returnType, WebResponseCallback<T> callback) {

    if (postData != null) {
        url += URLEncodedUtils.format(postData, "UTF-8");
    }
    getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    this.execute(callback, returnType);
}

public void sendOrderId(String url, List<Integer> postData,
        String httpMethod, Type returnType, WebResponseCallback<T> callback) {

    if (postData != null) {
        url += postData.toString();
    }
    getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    this.execute(callback, returnType);
}
```

Sending the name value pare works fine. But the `List<Integer>` passing dont work. how can i pass a `List<Integer>` to a web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can't pass a List you can just pass only the item list.
You could use JSON. 
Moreover, looking at your code you use GET method, i suggest to you to use POST because with GET you have the limit on the size of data you want to pass.

Comment: can we pass it as an Integer array to a web service?

Comment: If you represent it in XML or json you can.